# Subdirect product of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-algebra

Consider two classes of algebras(not necessarily of the same structure), say $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ and suppose the following claim:

---

An algebra is an $\mathbf{A}$-algebra if and only if it is a subdirect product of $\mathbf{B}$-algebras.

---

If $\mathbf{B}$ is closed under products and subalgebras, is it then fair to say that $\mathbf{A}$ is embedded in $\mathbf{B}$?

Comment: What do you mean with algebraic structure? Since you consider the hypothesis of $\mathbf B$ being closed under (the formation of?) products and subalgebras, is an algebraic structure a class of algebras? And in that case, what does it mean $\mathbf A$ to be embedded in $\mathbf B$?

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, under your assumptions, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are *equal*.  Every $\mathbf{A}$-algebra is a subalgebra of a direct product of $\mathbf{B}$-algebras, and hence a $\mathbf{B}$-algebra.  Conversely, every $\mathbf{B}$-algebra is a subdirect product of $\mathbf{B}$-algebras (just take the $1$-fold product consisting of the algebra itself), and thus an $\mathbf{A}$-algebra.

Comment: What would happen if one of the closure conditions would be removed?